# How can write two inner join in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi I want traslate this sql to rails active record

```
select a.*
from public.users a
inner join public.user_by_groups gp2 on gp2.user_id = a.id and gp2.active = 'true'
and gp2.group_id in 
(SELECT gp.group_id                     
  FROM public.users u
  inner join public.user_by_groups gp on gp.user_id = u.id and gp.active = 'true'
  where u.id = '4')
```

My models (With Many to Many Relation)

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_by_groups
  has_many :groups, through: :user_by_groups
end

class UserByGroup < ApplicationRecord
  # Relations
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group
end

class Group < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_by_groups
  has_many :users, through: :user_by_groups
end
```

And single have this first query:

```
    @class_mates = User.joins(:user_by_groups)
.where(user_by_groups: { user_id: 4 })
.where(user_by_groups: { active: true })
```

Comment: How about some reading? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Comment: What is your intended output here?  Is `@class_mates` supposed to hold all Users that belong to a specific active group that the current User also belongs to?

Comment: Exact, the data that I hope are all the users that are within the same group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
inner_user = Arel::Table.new(:users, as: :i_user)
inner_ubg = Arel::Table.new(:user_by_groups, as: :i_ubg)

User.joins(:groups).where(
  Arel::Nodes::In.new(
    Group.arel_table[:id],
    inner_user.
      project(inner_ubg[:group_id]).
      join(inner_ubg).on(inner_user[:id].eq(inner_ubg[:user_id])).
      where(inner_ubg[:active].eq(true)).
      where(inner_user[:id].eq(4))
  )
).to_sql

#=> SELECT "users".* FROM "users"
#     INNER JOIN "user_by_groups" ON "user_by_groups"."user_id" = "users"."id"
#     INNER JOIN "groups" ON "groups"."id" = "user_by_groups"."group_id"           
#     WHERE "groups"."id" IN ((
#       SELECT "i_ubg"."group_id" FROM "users" "i_user"
#       INNER JOIN "user_by_groups" "i_ubg" ON "i_user"."id" = "i_ubg"."user_id"
#       WHERE "i_ubg"."active" = 't' AND "i_user"."id" = 4
#     ))
```

Comment: Wow Arel is a excellent Tool, but if i want run the sql generated?, thanks for your answer

Comment: Very easy with ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute Thank you it works :D

Comment: Just remove the `to_sql` from the end, and you get just another ActiveRecord relation object that you can call `to_a`, `each`, etc. on.